# How to get the difference between 2 datetimes in python?

Tags: python, datetime

```
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime.now()  
end = datetime.datetime.now()

enter = ""  
result = end - start  
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"  
print("Welcome to the alphabet game!")  
print("Try to type the alphabet as fast as you can!")  

enter = input("when you are ready type 'go' : ")  
if enter == "go":  
    start  
    print("GO")  
    g = input("")  
if g == alphabet:  
    print("Well done!")  
    print("Your time was: ", result)
```

The problem is that the time it returns is just `00:00:00`
how would I get the 2 datetimes to work within the code itself, or to record the time when the user has finished and started the input? 
Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Because you assign to `result` and `end` *before* letting the user play. Also, the `start` in the first if-body is meaningless.

Comment: so how would I be able to get the times from inside the main body of the code?

Comment: @user3049392: Just assign to them, but after the first `if`, that's all ;)

Answer (score 0):

You set `start` and `end` just *once*, at the top. If you wanted to measure particular moments in time in your game, you need to call `datetime.datetime.now()` *at that moment*. Referring to `start` won't do that:

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"  
print("Welcome to the alphabet game!")  
print("Try to type the alphabet as fast as you can!")  
start = None

enter = input("when you are ready type 'go' : ")  
if enter == "go":  
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("GO")  
    g = input("")  
if g == alphabet:
    if not start:
        print("We have yet to start!")
    else: 
        print("Well done!")
        print("Your time was: ", datetime.datetime.now() - start)
```

Comment: but `print("Your time was: ", datetime.datetime.now() - start)` will possibly be more inprecise then necessary (even though in this specific case, it is negligible).

Comment: @phresnel: It'll tell you the time that passed, in day, seconds and *microseconds*, between `'GO'` being printed and the user entering the alphabet and the enter key. That's going to be precise enough for this game, really.

Comment: @phresnel: How more precise did you want to make this?

Comment: I would just go the standard route `print "GO"\nstart = time...\n...input()...\nend = time...`. That pattern will always work, is minimal, and will always be as precise as possible in every situation. As said, in this case it's negligible, but why not teach the canonical pattern to newcomers.

Comment: I fail to see how the sample I give in my post is less precise. `start` is set before `GO` is printed, but that difference is *less than microseconds*. I don't assign `end`, I just calculate the duration in an expression passed to the `print()` function. Again, that won't influence 'precision'.

Comment: Now, if you told me to use `timeit.default_timer` instead to get the right timer for the current platform for best precision measurements, you'd be on to something (albeit totally overkill for a simple timing game).

Comment: My point is more about semantics. I fail to see why one should measure `printing + work + printing` instead of just `work`. Yeah I know it does not matter much here; but why not add just another line and teach a pattern that is universally applicable to newcomers. If `print` shall be replaced by `show_fancy_success_animation` in the future, or you would emit to a web-frontend, one would have to be careful at several places instead of just one. Yeah I know it doesn't matter much for the OP, but then the OP doesn't matter much in real life and is itself just a (self-)tutorial.